# Azure DevOps Query all past iterations

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I am new to Azure DevOps queries and I am trying to build a simple query that would return all Tasks that have changed state today and belong to past iterations. In other words, how do I query all iterations before @CurrentIteration?

Here is what I have done so far:

```
Work Item Type = Task
State changed = @Today
```

So I need something like

```
Iteration Path < @CurrentIteration
```

But the < operation is not allowed on Iteration Path, and I can’t use @CurrentIteration with Iteration ID.

Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use the larger than/smaller than operator on Iterations, but you can select the parent Iteration and then use the "Under" operator, that will take all the items in the parent iteration and below. If you want to exclude the backlog itself you can also add a "and not in backlogIteration".

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it did not solve my issue directly, but it gave me a valuable idea on how to make a little change to the iterations structure which brought a lot of benefits and solved the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Now I'm curious how you solved it. You can always add a 2nd answer with your alternate solution.

Comment: I simply added a parent iteration for all the past iterations and now I use it with “Under” or “Not Under” for queries when I need to include or exclude past iterations. It is probably not an ideal solution, but the problem in my organisation is that there are many users of the process that do not really understand it and I have to identify reliably all the “mistakes” and misplaced work items.

Comment: I need to do the same thing but work in a really big organization.  Is this answer still applicable (its a little more than 1 year old).  I could really use an @olditeration type macro.

Comment: No change. And I don't expect one.